# Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'ID'

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql

I am getting the exception "Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'ID'" when using Linq to Sql , I am leaving the ID property blank , but I have set my ID to auto-generate in my DBML file.  This will work fine when I insert without an ID and let sql auto generate for me not using linq.  The problem is LINQ is throwing an exception because it sees that ID is empty , even though if LINQ would just let it go through SQL is ok with it.

```
    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_ID", AutoSync=AutoSync.OnInsert, DbType="Int NOT NULL", IsPrimaryKey=true, IsDbGenerated=true)]
    public int ID
    {
        get
        {
            return this._ID;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this._ID != value))
            {
                this.OnIDChanging(value);
                this.SendPropertyChanging();
                this._ID = value;
                this.SendPropertyChanged("ID");
                this.OnIDChanged();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sorry to ask, but are you 100% sure the ID is set to auto-generate?

Comment: I'll check again in Sql , I have Identity = yes, Identity Increment  , and Identity Seed Set , and in DBML I have Auto-Generated = true

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to include 'IDENTITY' in your column definition:

```
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_ID", AutoSync=AutoSync.OnInsert, DbType="Int NOT NULL IDENTITY", IsPrimaryKey=true, IsDbGenerated=true)]
public int ID
{ ... }
```

If that wont fix it try adding `UpdateCheck=UpdateCheck.Never` as well.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, caused by a **missing key in my mapping configurations** (I only had one key, and not a composite, as it should have been).

Thought I'd share the answer, since my problem was similar, but my solution is a little different.

In short, my context class and configurations look like this:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        // Loads the configuration:
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new MyMyDataClassConfiguration()); 
    }

    // ...
}


public class MyDataClassConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<MyDataClass>
{
    public MyDataClassConfiguration()
    {
        ToTable("MyDataTableName"); // Maps to table

        // Specify composite key (I was missing a key here)
        HasKey(data => new {data.First_Key_Name, data.Second_Key_Name });
    }
}
```