# Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Id', column is identity and PK

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

This question has been asked quite a few times on SO but none of the other answers have helped. I'm inserting into a table (SQL Server 2014, EF 6), and I'm getting the error `Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Id' ... column does not allow nulls.` The `Id` column is set in my DB to be the primary key AND is an identity column, I've triple-checked that. I'm able to insert without specifying an Id using T-SQL in SSMS, but EF fails. It's passing `0` for the value; I don't understand why it's not being accepted. I do not use any data annotations, I only use fluent mapping.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15326820/cannot-insert-the-value-null-into-column-id) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31528627/web-api-error-cannot-insert-the-value-null-into-column-id) both use data annotations and shouldn't be used for this project. This has worked correctly before without annotations; I have no idea what changed to cause this.

Class:

```
namespace Nop.Core.Domain.Common
{
    public partial class GenericAttribute : BaseEntity
    {
        // Id is inherited from BaseEntity
        public virtual int EntityId { get; set; }
        public virtual string KeyGroup { get; set; }
        public virtual string Key { get; set; }
        public virtual string Value { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Fluent map:

```
namespace Nop.Data.Mapping.Common
{
    public partial class GenericAttributeMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<GenericAttribute>
    {
        public GenericAttributeMap()
        {
            ToTable("GenericAttribute");
            HasKey(ga => ga.Id);

            Property(ga => ga.KeyGroup).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(400);
            Property(ga => ga.Key).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(400);
            Property(ga => ga.Value).IsRequired();
        }
    }
}
```

Code to update:

```
prop = new GenericAttribute()
       {
           EntityId = entity.Id,
           Key = key,
           KeyGroup = keyGroup,
           Value = valueStr
       };
// calls _repository.Insert(), which then calls _context.SaveChanges();
InsertAttribute(prop);
```

Profiler only shows `SELECT`, no `INSERT` attempts:

```
{SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[EntityId] AS [EntityId], 
    [Extent1].[KeyGroup] AS [KeyGroup], 
    [Extent1].[Key] AS [Key], 
    [Extent1].[Value] AS [Value]
FROM [dbo].[GenericAttribute] AS [Extent1]}
```

Comment: I'd suspect EF passes the Id itself, so it won't ask DBMS at all. use fluent API with Property(x=>x.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity); to fix this.

Comment: @DevilSuichiro I just tried that, same error is thrown.

Comment: Can you use profiler and verify the SQL that's being generated?

Comment: @DrewJordan Profiler doesn't show any `INSERT`s, only `SELECT`s. I've added that to the post.

Comment: @Vaindil Can you try Database.Log to catch the insert statement?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you are missing a setting on the column of auto_increment.  Look at something like this on your table:

MySQL:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name MODIFY COLUMN coumn_name INT auto_increment
```

T-SQL:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD column_name int NOT NULL IDENTITY (1,1) PRIMARY KEY
```

Comment: `AUTO_INCREMENT` in **MS SQL Server**? Rather `IDENTITY` and OP says: `" The Id column is set in my DB to be the primary key AND is an identity column, I've triple-checked that.`"

Comment: So then maybe you just need to specify the increment piece.    ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD table_name int NOT NULL IDENTITY (1,1)

Answer (score 0):

Try add in the following to your mapping configuration class

```
Property(ga => ga.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not all that familiar with FluentAPI, but my hunch is that this stems from your inheritance hierarchy: that is, the NULL value it sees is actually on your `BaseEntity` and not the `GenericAttribute` itself. [This blog](http://romiller.com/2013/01/29/ef6-code-first-configuring-unmapped-base-types/) suggests that you should be mapping using `HasKey()` on the parent class, and *not* the child class. It won't matter to the database, but EF is probably trying to find the instance on the parent.